# Compile bazel, but host is behind a SQUID proxy

Tags: proxy, compilation, bazel, http-proxy, squid

I'd like to compile a very recent bazel on Fedora28, so I did a `git clone` from the guthub.com repo.
Bazel requires bazel for compiling, I have installed a bazel 0.22 from Fedora/Copr repository as a "bazel bootstrap".
I ran the `compile.sh` script (form bazel source tree) which tells to run `bazel build //src:bazel`. So far, everything is fine.
As said in the title of this question my machine is behind a SQUID proxy (running on another machine on port 1080 with no auth), and I have `http_proxy` + `https_proxy` pointing to that proxy, and `no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1` (they are in `/etc/environment` so everyone gets it).
It seems like bazel does not like proxies at all, for I have the following result (see copy of output below, the address 10.200.255.254:1080 is my proxy).

I don't understand why bazel can't download file since it works fine with wget, curl of dnf.

For example: `bazel 0.22 says it can't download https://mirror.bazel.build/openjdk/azul-zulu11.29.3-ca-jdk11.0.2/zulu11.29.3-ca-jdk11.0.2-linux_x64-minimal-90755145cb6e6418584d8603cd5fa9afbb30aecc-1549209948.tar.gz,
but wget actually can download it (I have tried, it works perfectly).

It seems like bazel does not care about my proxy envvar. What should I do ?

```
Extract from the command-line (error message)
$ bazel build //src:bazel
INFO: Invocation ID: 7f267cd1-51f6-4d91-85db-afc797b1323b
ERROR: /home/denielp/bazel/src/BUILD:219:1: no such package '@openjdk_linux_minimal//file': java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://mirror.bazel.build/openjdk/azul-zulu11.29.3-ca-jdk11.0.2/zulu11.29.3-ca-jdk11.0.2-linux_x64-minimal-90755145cb6e6418584d8603cd5fa9afbb30aecc-1549209948.tar.gz] to /home/denielp/.cache/bazel/_bazel_denielp/4884ab1c8a85fee5e1fa7c3b610b7efb/external/openjdk_linux_minimal/file/zulu-linux-minimal.tar.gz: Proxy address 10.200.255.254:1080 is not a valid URL and referenced by '//src:embedded_jdk_minimal_cached'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//src:bazel' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 12.851s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (1 packages loaded, 1 target configured)
currently loading: tools/build_defs/repo
Fetching @openjdk_linux_minimal; fetching 12s
Fetching @remotejdk_linux; fetching 12s
Fetching @bazel_skylib; fetching 12s
Fetching @desugar_jdk_libs; fetching 12s
```

Comment: Looking at `Proxy address 10.200.255.254:1080 is not a valid URL` did you not forget to include scheme (presumably `https://` or `http://`) with your proxy definition?

Comment: You are right, and I had the same idea and tried it. It just turns the "is not a valid URL" error into another error ([Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway"]). Actually, this proxy works, I can use dnf (I am runnning F28), yum wget, curl, firefox... Bazel is the only product that causes such an issue.

Comment: Finally, it seems like Bazel downloader is quite messy, and does not manage well http_proxy/https_proxy, the best I could do was : 1) run the compilation , 2) look into the error message to see what file is to be downloaded, 3) get it manually, using wget into a local ~/DISTDIR directory, 4) run bazel with "--distdir" option to make it point to ~/DISTDIR... Then run this iteratively until bazel has all the plugins it needs. This is not a solution, just a painful  workaround. It should be great to have bazel developers fixing this.